# Outlook : change autocomplete "to' field behavior to enable domain lookup

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autocomplete

When Writing an email, the "To" field is today unable to lookup users through the domain name with the autocomplete feature, searching for names and surnames works yet nothing after the @ is searched through by the software.

As comparison, in Thunderbird, if the mail is in the local address book, it's doable.
[image: Thunderbird domain lookup]

So can the "To" Field search behavior be tuned to enable domain lookup in the software through GPO / Configuration edition?
Without plugins ideally, but if it's needed, which ones ?

Comment: In Outlook, in a New Email, click on Address Book on the main Ribbon. You can add address books here to see the Domain or Exchange Host Address book.

Comment: Indeed, the address book has a setting to enable a wider search, but my users and me are looking for a simple way to enable domain lookup when typing the email in the field. Even with M365, Outlook gets slow to open new windows including the address book.

For instance, this would help when using the integrated meeting with Teams / Teamviewer options.

Comment: Try the following:  "When opening the address book, choose the name of the address book you want to use by default and list it first. 
Click OK, and close the dialog box"  This will change the default address book and may assist you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the behavior of Outlook autocomplete feature is by design and we could make changes to it. If you would still like the feature you mentioned, I'm afraid that you might need add-ins, or it is suggested to submit your feedback via Outlook UserVoice.